# The canonical way to structure a Class (and to avoid the "name 'self' is not defined") error

Tags: python

I'm new to classes in Python and could use some assistance.

I have the following (admittedly poorly-written) class:

```
import QuantLib as ql

class European_Option:
    
    day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

    def __init__(self, underlying_price, strike_price, maturity_date, risk_free_rate, implied_volatility, calculation_date, dividend_rate):
        self.underlying_price = underlying_price
        self.strike_price = strike_price
        self.maturity_date = ql.Date(maturity_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
        self.risk_free_rate = risk_free_rate
        self.implied_volatility = implied_volatility
        self.calculation_date = ql.Date(calculation_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
        self.dividend_rate = dividend_rate
        
    option_type = ql.Option.Call
        
    payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, self.strike_price)
    
    exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(self.maturity_date)
        
    self.european_option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)
        
    spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(
            ql.SimpleQuote(self.underlying_price))

    flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(self.calculation_date, 
                        self.risk_free_rate, 
                        self.day_count))
        
    dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(self.calculation_date, 
                        self.dividend_rate, 
                        self.day_count))
        
    flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
            ql.BlackConstantVol(self.calculation_date, 
                                self.calendar, 
                                self.implied_volatility, 
                                self.day_count))
        
    bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(spot_handle, 
                                                dividend_yield, 
                                                flat_ts, 
                                                flat_vol_ts)

    def get_bs_price(self):
        self.european_option.setPricingEngine(ql.AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsm_process))
        bs_price = european_option.NPV() / underlying_price
        return bs_price
 
    def get_delta(self):
        delta = self.european_option.delta()
        return delta
    
    def get_gamma(self):
        gamma = european_option.gamma()
        return gamma
    
    def get_vega(self):
        vega = european_option.vega()
        return vega
    
    def get_theta(self):
        theta = european_option.theta()
        return theta
```

The error that I'm seeing is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10756/3430584687.py in <module>
      1 import QuantLib as ql
      2 
----> 3 class European_Option:
      4 
      5     day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10756/3430584687.py in European_Option()
     17     option_type = ql.Option.Call
     18 
---> 19     payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, self.strike_price)
     20 
     21     exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(self.maturity_date)

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The following procedural code (from which I wrote the class above) works just fine:

```
maturity_date = ql.Date(25, 3, 2022)  #(15, 1, 2016)
spot_price = 41684.7 #127.62
strike_price = 55000 #130
volatility = 0.732384295  #0.20
dividend_rate =  0.0163
option_type = ql.Option.Call
        
risk_free_rate = .01 #0.001
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
        
calculation_date = ql.Date(10, 1, 2022)  #(8, 5, 2015)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, strike_price)
exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(maturity_date)
european_option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)

spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(
            ql.SimpleQuote(spot_price)
        )
flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, 
                           risk_free_rate, 
                           day_count)
        )
dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, 
                           dividend_rate, 
                           day_count)
        )
flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
            ql.BlackConstantVol(calculation_date, 
                                calendar, 
                                volatility, 
                                day_count)
        )
bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(spot_handle, 
                                                   dividend_yield, 
                                                   flat_ts, 
                                                   flat_vol_ts)

european_option.setPricingEngine(ql.AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsm_process))

bs_price = european_option.NPV() / spot_price

bs_price

0.041619876117798014
```

Questions:

1. What is causing the `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` error in the class above?
2. Would someone kindly show me the correct (i.e. canonical) way to write this class?

Thank you in advance for helping an OOP newbie!

Comment: The cause of this error is that `self` is not defined at the point where it is accessed. Since you`re defining a class attribute, you do not have access to properties of an instance at this point.

Comment: All those class attributes that reference `self` need to be instance attributes, so they need to be inside a method, probably your `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a reading of the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) about classes.

Q1. What is causing the `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` error in the class above?

A: `self` refers to an object of a class. You cannot reference an object before you create one.

Q2. Would someone kindly show me the correct (i.e. canonical) way to write this class?

A: You could add the class properties you defined to the `__init__` method, as you did with some properties.

```
import QuantLib as ql


class European_Option:

    day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

    def __init__(
        self,
        underlying_price,
        strike_price,
        maturity_date,
        risk_free_rate,
        implied_volatility,
        calculation_date,
        dividend_rate,
    ):
        self.underlying_price = underlying_price
        self.strike_price = strike_price
        self.maturity_date = ql.Date(maturity_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
        self.risk_free_rate = risk_free_rate
        self.implied_volatility = implied_volatility
        self.calculation_date = ql.Date(calculation_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
        self.dividend_rate = dividend_rate

        self.option_type = ql.Option.Call

        self.payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(self.option_type, self.strike_price)

        self.exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(self.maturity_date)
        self.european_option = ql.VanillaOption(self.payoff, self.exercise)

        self.spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(self.underlying_price))

        self.flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(self.calculation_date, self.risk_free_rate, self.day_count)
        )

        self.dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(self.calculation_date, self.dividend_rate, self.day_count)
        )

        self.flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
            ql.BlackConstantVol(
                self.calculation_date,
                self.calendar,
                self.implied_volatility,
                self.day_count,
            )
        )

        self.bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(
            self.spot_handle, self.dividend_yield, self.flat_ts, self.flat_vol_ts
        )

    def get_bs_price(self):
        self.european_option.setPricingEngine(ql.AnalyticEuropeanEngine(self.bsm_process))
        bs_price = self.european_option.NPV() / self.underlying_price
        return bs_price

    def get_delta(self):
        delta = self.european_option.delta()
        return delta

    def get_gamma(self):
        gamma = self.european_option.gamma()
        return gamma

    def get_vega(self):
        vega = self.european_option.vega()
        return vega

    def get_theta(self):
        theta = self.european_option.theta()
        return theta
```